# How to remove duplicate elements in an array using BITWISE operators?

Tags: java, python, arrays, bit-manipulation, xor

I was just thinking, maybe we could remove duplicate numbers using bitwise operators. Is this possible? For instance, using XOR if we have same number, we can make that as zero

`a[i] = number ^ scanner.nextInt()`

```java
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 6;
    int[] a = new int[n];
     System.out.println("Enter array elements:");
    a[0] = s.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
      a[i] = a[0] ^ s.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm stuck. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I was just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. XOR makes it zero if it is the same number; that is not removing the number, just making it `0` (maybe useful if zero is not allowed, but still it is not removed)
   Example: entering `1`, `1` will result in having `[1, 0, ...]` in the array
2. XOR makes a (total) different number if it is not the same number
   Example: entering `1` and `2` will result in having `[1, 3 ,...]` in the array
3. that algorithm only compares the entered value with the last entry of the array, not testing against any previous entry
   Example: entering `1`, `2`, `1` will result in having `[1, 2, 1, ...]` in the array

Answer: it may even be possible, but I don't think it is simple neither to implement nor to understand